# Gnosis Safe: Unexpected Delegate call while sending multiple transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe

We are always getting the error **Unexpected Delegate call** when using **Create a MultiSend transaction** as mentioned here https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md#propose-transaction

The queued transaction on confirmation is working but showing Unexpected Delegate call warning message and data is encoded. If we submit batch txns using gnosis UI, there is no warning and data is nicely shown under "Action"

While It works fine when use **Create a single transaction.**
There is an open issue on this : https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/3471
Anyone facing similar issue while using `safe-core-sdk` and `safe-service-client` module?

Comment: This is working okay on mainnet. Issue is only on testnet (Goerli).

Comment: We update the configuration on Goerli, so this should not happen anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Due to security reasons this warning is shown if a multisend contract is used that is not "known" by our services. As delegatecalls are critical this is to avoid that a malicious contract is used with a delegatecall.

As these "known" contract need to be setup in the service the best is to report this on the Safe discord, so that the contract in question can be evaluated.

In the case you mentioned this should obviously be added to the known contracts as this is a contract deployed by the Safe team.